# Request failed: method not allowed (405) in Afnetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I want to fetch json data from server via Afnetworking but i got an error.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager=[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [[AFJSONRequestSerializer alloc] init];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

[manager POST:url parameters:0 success:^ void(AFHTTPRequestOperation * operationManager, id result)
 {

      NSLog(@"My Result Is :%@", result);



 } failure:^ void(AFHTTPRequestOperation * operationManger, NSError * error)
 {

 NSLog(@"Error :%@", error.localizedDescription);
 }];
```

Comment: That's a server error, so why are you showing client code?

Comment: Actually web service is working fine on Android platform but while i try to integrate in iOS i got this error.

Comment: OK show the Android client code as well then.

Comment: 405 usually means you either tried a POSt on something that only allows PUT, or vice-versa, or tried http: on a method that requires https. check the request method and encoding type from Web service client (postman or ARC).

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] isReachable]) {
    //Add your request object to an AFHTTPRequestOperation
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];

        operation.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation,id _responseObject) {

            id responseObject   = [ NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData : _responseObject
                                                                   options : kNilOptions
                                                                     error : nil ] ;


            NSLog(@"Response:%@",responseObject);
             // Success ;
            if( _success )
            {
                _success( responseObject ) ;

            }

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);

            if( _failure )
            {
                _failure( error) ;
            }

        }];

        //call start on your request operation
        [operation start];

    }
    else
    {
        [Utility showInterNetConnectionMessage];

        NSError *error;

        if( _failure )
        {
            _failure( error) ;
        }

    }
```